# Twitter username autocompletion

Tags: twitter

I would like to allow users on my website to nominate other Twitter users in a text input field. I intend to provide an autocompletion feature similar to Twitter's mention typeahead when a user enters @ in a Tweet.

@JakeHarding developed similar functionality in a demonstration of [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/). Unfortunately, the logic is hidden in a herokuapp.

I would be grateful for any support you can provide.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the response from [typeahead-js-twitter-api-proxy.herokuapp.com](https://typeahead-js-twitter-api-proxy.herokuapp.com/demo/search?q=twitter) it's just a proxy for [GET users/search](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/search). So just set up a server that takes the auto-complete text, wraps it in OAuth, and forwards it to the Twitter API. You'll have to be very mindful of [rate limits](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting) though. Autocomplete will burn through that in no time.

Comment: The app is certainly a wrapper for the Twitter API but given that this is a public demonstration for a very popular library the authors must have a method to get around the rate limitation.